# linear mixed model with response variable with many zeros

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, zero-inflation

My response variable is accuracy (0 or 1) with 10 trials per subject. I thought about treating the response variable as a percentage and logit-transforming it to deal with its boundedness so that the predicted values were sensible, but this doesn't deal with the non-normality of the errors due to a large number of zeros in the data (i.e., About 25 of 83 subjects have only zeros (i.e., their accuracy rate was 0%). So now I am thinking about using a mixed logistic regression (i.e., generalized linear mixed model via glmer() in R with family = binomial("logit") and accounting for dependence among observations by modeling intercepts for subjects.

Is GLMM an adequate way to deal with the zeros? Is there another more appropriate model I could use that isn't overly complicated?

Also, any suggestions for how to approach this in R?

Edit: Here are my data (which if I were to run a GLMM I would convert back to long form):

```
zz <- "id successes ageMonths
2   2            10      83.1
3   3             0      82.0
4   4             0      80.2
5   6             0      63.5
6   7             3      85.2
7   8             0      84.0
9  10             0      83.2
10 11             0      74.8
11 12             0      65.6
12 14             0      81.8
13 15             0      83.0
14 16             2      70.2
15 17             0      76.2
16 18            10      64.4
17 19             0      79.9
18 20             1      76.9
19 21             0      71.3
20 22             0      79.8
21 23             0      82.1
22 24             1      79.8
23 25             0      77.1
24 26            10      63.5
25 27             0      80.3
26 28             0      81.8
27 29            10      68.8
28 30             0      81.5
29 31             0      74.8
30 32             0      60.4
31 33             0      77.8
32 35            10      69.1
34 37             0      70.4
35 38             0      83.3
36 39             3      69.2
37 40             0      77.4
38 41             0      77.2
39 42             9      64.3 
40 43             9      69.2
41 44             0      68.4
42 45             1      60.3
43 46             3      73.1
44 47            10      67.4
45 48             0      67.2
46 49             8      68.0
47 50             0      60.8
48 51             0      63.5
49 52             0      66.4
50 53             3      71.7
51 54             0      67.4
52 55             0      60.2
53 56            10      70.8
54 57             3      78.1
55 58            10      61.4
56 59             1      61.3
57 60             0      60.9
58 61             0      67.3
59 62             0      73.2
60 63             0      70.8
61 64             0      64.8
62 65             0      62.4
63 66             6      73.3
64 67             0      62.3
65 68            10      63.3
66 69            10      60.1
67 70             0      72.6
68 71            10      63.6
69 72             7      73.0
70 73             0      61.3
71 74             6      83.7
72 75            10      82.2
73 76             7      82.7
74 77            10      61.1
75 78             0      71.8
77 80             3      70.3
78 81             0      62.5
79 82             4      72.3
80 83             5      73.1
81 84             0      70.4
82 85             1      75.4
83 86             0      77.1
84 87             0      75.6
85 88             0      73.4
86 89             0      73.8
87 90             0      72.3"
Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE); Data
```

Edit 2: clarity

Comment: Is there anything changing across their 10 trials? You could use a simple logistic regression w/ a binomial response.

Comment: @gung: No, nothing is changing across the 10 trials. But if I use a simple logistic regression w/ binomial response then I'm not accounting for dependence among the 10 observations, right? Unless I use a percentage as the dv and logit-transform it? But is this really dealing with the problem of all the zeros and the non-normal error distribution? Also, any suggestions for how to implement your solution in R?

Comment: A LMM contains fixed effects and random effects. Which are those, in your case? And, are all the 83 subjects from the same group?

Comment: @smndpln, fixed effects would be other continuous measures I haven't mentioned, like age, IQ, etc., and the random effect would be subject (because each completed 10 trials). Dependent variable would be accuracy on a given trial.

Comment: Age and IQ are usually treated as covariates/random effects, unless you have categories (high/low IQ, for example). And, are you sure that you want the accuracy on a single trial to be the DV? It is more appropriate to use the average accuracy over the 10 trials, in this case.

Comment: @smndpln, no I am not sure that's what I want, which is why I posted the question. I am trying to select the model that is most appropriate. If I use average accuracy then there are two issues 1) the response variable is between 0 and 1 so some of the predicted values will be impossible, and 2) the frequency of zeros in the data is high. If only 1 was a problem I'd use a logit transformation, but I'm more worried about addressing 2. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you try to implement a linear model (for example ANOVA, if you have fixed effects) on mean accuracies using only subjects with accuracy > 0 (58 subjects)?
Can you be sure that partecipants with a very low accuracy have a reliable score? (Were they really doing the task?)

Comment: @smndpln, the subjects with zeros are reliable/their scores are meaningful, so I'd like to retain them in the analysis somehow (I think it would be questionable to exclude them, unless this is standard practice for addressing the problem I'm dealing with).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your response data are all $0$s and $1$s.  That means your response variable is distributed as a [binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution); it is not normal.  You should not try to transform it to achieve normality (that will never work anyway), and you should not use a "linear" model (in the sense that is meant in *linear regression* or *linear mixed model*, which here mean that they are for a normally distributed $Y$ variable).

Instead, you should use a model that is appropriate for a binomial response.  Specifically, you should use some form of [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).  It is most common for logistic regression to have a single Bernoulli trial (a single $0$ or $1$) as the response, but since nothing is varying over the 10 responses, there is no need to take anything else into account and a binomial logistic regression is fine.

The excellent UCLA statistics help site has a tutorial on logistic regression in `R` [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm).  To see a quick example of a logistic regression in `R` when the response is multiple Bernoulli trials, you might want to take a look at my answer here:  [Difference in output between SAS's proc genmod and R's glm](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/162996/7290).  Lastly, although written in a different context, my answer here: [Difference between logit and probit models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30909/7290), has a lot of information about logistic regression that may help you understand it better.

---

*Update:*
The $0$s do matter, although perhaps not the way you think (you could just as easily say the $10$s are the issue).  I take a look at your data below:

```r
Data = read.table(text=zz, header=TRUE)
m = glm(cbind(successes, 10-successes)~ageMonths, Data, family=binomial)
summary(m)
# Call:
# glm(formula = cbind(successes, 10 - successes) ~ ageMonths, family = binomial, 
#     data = Data)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
# -3.151  -2.433  -1.964   1.539   6.115  
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
# (Intercept)  2.87265    0.79011   3.636 0.000277 ***
# ageMonths   -0.05505    0.01116  -4.935 8.03e-07 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  
# 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
# 
#     Null deviance: 734.18  on 82  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 708.78  on 81  degrees of freedom
# AIC: 763.09
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
1-pchisq(708.78, df=81)  # [1] 0
```

The key feature here is that you have a residual deviance of $709$ on $81$ df.  If your data were a simple draw from a binomial distribution, that shouldn't happen.  We can formally test for overdispersion by comparing that to its corresponding chi-squared distribution.  You can see that the p-value is very small (`R` only reports $0$).

There are a couple of ways you could have overdispersion in binomial data.  One is that you have a poorly fitting model, e.g., you are missing interaction or polynomial terms (cf., [Test logistic regression model using residual deviance and degrees of freedom](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/248978/7290)).  Another possibility is that the data aren't actually distributed as a binomial, or that there are latent groupings.  An easy first check is to look at your data using a method that is based on different assumptions.  Below, I plot your data and overlay a [LOWESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) fit.  Because the y-values come only at discrete points, I jitter them slightly to ensure that multiple copies of the same value remain visible.  The overdispersion is easy to see.  It is also possible that you should be using a cubic polynomial, but to test that on this dataset because you saw it in this plot is invalid.

```r
windows()
  with(Data, plot(ageMonths, jitter(successes, amount=.3)))
  lines(with(Data, lowess(ageMonths, successes)), col="red")
```

[image]

Given that you really have overdispersion, rather than a too simple functional form leading to an underfitted model, one hack is to use the quasibinomial 'distribution'.  (That isn't really a different distribution, it just estimates the overdispersion and multiplies your standard errors by that factor in hopes that that will provide adequate protection.)  Note that the output is largely the same, but the SEs and the p-values are larger, and it now says "Dispersion parameter ...taken to be 7.7" instead of 1.

```r
mqb = glm(cbind(successes, 10-successes)~ageMonths, Data, family=quasibinomial)
summary(mqb)
# Call:
# glm(formula = cbind(successes, 10 - successes) ~ ageMonths, family = quasibinomial, 
#     data = Data)
# 
# Deviance Residuals: 
#    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
# -3.151  -2.433  -1.964   1.539   6.115  
# 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
# (Intercept)  2.87265    2.19467   1.309   0.1943  
# ageMonths   -0.05505    0.03099  -1.776   0.0794 .
# ---
# Signif. codes:  
# 0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# (Dispersion parameter for quasibinomial family taken to be 7.715571)
# 
#     Null deviance: 734.18  on 82  degrees of freedom
# Residual deviance: 708.78  on 81  degrees of freedom
# AIC: NA
# 
# Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

The question is whether you believe that hack is adequate to cover you.  I'm not confident.  You seem to have a mix of mostly two latent groupings where for one the questions are way too hard and another for whom the questions are trivial (with perhaps a few intermediate people).  Unfortunately, there may be no way to really estimate who is who and control for their abilities independently of the number of successes you observe here.  To be honest, I suspect you won't really be able to learn anything from these data.  At any rate, another strategy is not to make any distributional assumptions at all.  Instead, you could use ordinal logistic regression, which would be my choice here.

```r
library(rms)
om = orm(successes~ageMonths, Data)
om
# Logistic (Proportional Odds) Ordinal Regression Model
# 
# orm(formula = successes ~ ageMonths, data = Data)
# Frequencies of Responses
# 
#  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 49  5  1  6  1  1  2  2  1  2 13 
# 
#                      Model Likelihood          Discrimination          Rank Discrim.    
#                         Ratio Test                 Indexes                Indexes       
# Obs            83    LR chi2      2.23    R2                  0.028    rho     0.161    
# Unique Y       11    d.f.            1    g                   0.386                     
# Median Y        0    Pr(> chi2) 0.1351    gr                  1.472                     
# max |deriv| 1e-06    Score chi2   2.21    |Pr(Y>=median)-0.5| 0.096                     
#                      Pr(> chi2) 0.1367                                                  
# 
#           Coef    S.E.   Wald Z Pr(>|Z|)
# ageMonths -0.0447 0.0303 -1.48  0.1397
```

The key test is the likelihood ratio test of the model as a whole at the top (2.2, df=1, p=.135).

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "but since nothing is varying over the 10 responses, there is no need to take anything else into account and a binomial logistic regression is fine"? My understanding is that if I use a logistic regression model it would need to be a mixed model (implemented in R via glmer) because although nothing varies across the 10 trials recorded *per subject*, there are multiple subjects and each contributes multiple trials, hence dependence needs to be accounted for in the model.

Comment: Also, I could take the average of each subject's 10 responses as my response variable, which could in theory be transformed so that the errors are normal. I don't think this will work here because there are many 0%s and 100%s, but I'm wondering if there's another way to address the non-normality issue without switching to a trial-level model (i.e., sticking with percents as my response variable).

Comment: @panpsych77, the idea is that 10 responses amount to a singe Y-value drawn from the set {0,1,2,...,9,10}. For each person in the study, you have a single number of correct answers (out of 10). OTOH, if you have a set of measurements (say blood pressure measurements classified as 'high' or 'normal') from a set of patients, where some were in the morning, and some were in the evening, then you'd have 10 responses but where `time of day` varied over the 10 responses, so you couldn't do what I'm suggesting. If nothing varies over the 10 responses, you have a single number for each patient.

Comment: For additional examples of running a logistic regression in R with multiple Bernoulli trials, you can read through [this set of answers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a7290%20glm%20cbind%20) I've given where I've done that.

Comment: thanks but I'm still a bit confused! If use logistic regression and code the response variable in the way you suggest in your response, my p values are much, much smaller than if I were to run a linear model with percentage as the dependent variable. This makes me suspicious that the logistic regression analysis is treating each of the 10 trials as independent data points rather than as dependent/embedded within subjects. Also, does this address the problem that many subjects had zero successes? (I'm assuming yes because normality of errors isn't assumed?)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @panpsych77. You should not actually code the response as 0, ..., 10 in the `glm()` call. Look at the many code examples I've referenced. You should be using `glm(cbind(successes, failures)~...`. None of this has anything to do w/ normality, & you shouldn't use a normal model or predict %s as those are invalid. (Imagine someone saying, 'when I compare your way to something that is invalid by definition, I get a different result'.) Can you just post your data?

Comment: I posted my data above. I used exactly the code you suggest to run the analysis. I see your point re: different results. It's just striking to me that the p values are so different (usually I don't see such a striking difference when I use different analyses on the same data so I just want to be sure I'm doing this correctly).  But my biggest concern is all the zeros for successes. Just want to confirm if it's a problem for this analysis.

Comment: thanks for your update. That is a lot for me to wrap my head around, but one question remains: I've read that in order for a count variable to be described by a binomial distribution, the observations (trials) must be independent, but in my case they aren't (subjects each contributed 10 trials). Why is it not appropriate to model my data the way I suggested - using a glmm with a dichotomous response variable (success or failure on one trial) and modeling the dependence between trials (i.e., the 10 trials got from each subject) by including a random intercept for subjects in the model?

Comment: @panpsych77, your data *are* independent, conditional on subject, which is what is required. A GLMM is a much more complicated model. Among other things, it requires that the distribution of random effects is normal, and yours certainly won't even be close.

Comment: You're welcome, @panpsych77.

Comment: @gung it might be better to replace the statement "linear regression or linear mixed model (...) are for **a normally distributed Y variable**" by "linear regression or linear mixed model (...) are for **normally distributed residuals**"