# Study of an experimental regression with a percentage as the dependent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, multiple-regression, econometrics

I am trying to estimate the effect of an experimental intervention (random assignation to treatment and control groups) with the percentage of people in each group assisting to government services as the outcome variable. If i just wanted to know the impact of the intervention, a simple difference in the percentages would be it, right?

However, if I want to use a regression to control for other predictor of the variance in order to get a more precise estimate, my guess is that I should use a logistic regression, right? Then, I can obtain the average marginal effects to calculate the effect of the intervention on the probability of a person being enrolled in government services.

Nontheless, I find that this unnecesarily complicates the analysis. Would it be wrong to use an MCO instead? I have read [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284843/percentage-as-dependent-variable-in-multiple-linear-regression) that it might be problematic. But is that still the case in an experimental setting, where I am only interested in the coefficient of a dummy independent variable?