# Inconsistency between multivariate logistic regression and independent t test

Tags: regression, logistic, t-test, multivariate-analysis

I have data in which there are 1 dependent continuous variable ($Y$) and 20 independent continuous variables ($X$s). I discretized $Y$ into two categories ($low$ and $high$). Then, I applied independent samples t test taking the discretized $Y$ as grouping variables. Next, according to to test result, of the 20 continuous variables, 5 variables had different means Y. Finally, I applied multivariate logistic regression model taking discretized $Y$ as the dependent variable. This time, it was seen that none of the 20 variables had significant p values.

How should I interpret this?

Thanks

Günal

Comment: It's not at all clear to us what you mean by " 5 variables had different means Y."  What five variables?  What different means Y?  Do you mean to say that only 5 of the 20 variables you tested appeared to be "statistically significant" when you performed t-tests one by one?  If so, did you control from Type I error inflation when you did so?

Also, why do you assume there should be consistence between a logistic regression and a t-test?  One uses the logistic distribution, the other a t-distribution.  They are entirely different tests on arbitrarily grouped data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What exactly do you expect to be consistent? In a t test you have t and p values while in a logistic regression you have odds ratio, wald statistic and p values. So it is unclear to me what statistic you expect to be the same. The p values?
2. Why do you expect the results being the same? In a t test you compare the means between two groups while in a logistic regression [the model is trying to estimate a function that maps the covariate values to how p changes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396565/what-is-actually-being-modeled-in-binomial-logistic-regression/404177?r=SearchResults#404177) where p determines the shape of the Bernoulli distribution.
3. As long as the predictors are not orthogonal (= uncorrelated) it can always be the case that in a bivariat analysis one predictor is significant but in a multivariat analysis the same predictor [isn't significant anymore](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_the_Multiple_regression_model_not_significant_while_simple_regression_for_the_same_variables_is_significant/amp) So the situation you describe doesn't seem unsual to me in this regard. But the opposite can be true, as well: in caae of a [suppression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2254615/) a predictor that was not significant in a bivariat analysis the same predictor can be significant in a multivariate analysis.

@ "How should I interpret this?": You should choose the analysis that answers your research question. If you are interested in mean difference between two groups you can use the t test. If you want to predict a binary variable you can use the logistic regression. Alhtough as I understood you broke up a continuous variable into two groups which can be a bad idea (see [here](https://scholar.google.de/scholar?hl=de&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=continuous+variable+into+groups+not+a+good+idea&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&u=%23p%3DChxLXBUEC7kJ) or [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous)). If your main problem is to decide what variables to include in the model because the bivariate and the multivariate p values differ you should read about variable selection methods (without ignoring the theoretical background).